# Why does only one image from the two render?

Tags: html, image, layout

With the following markup, I always get the same look as when for an image that isn't found: its `alt` and `title` still there but no pic.

```
<div class="def-orange">
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <p>
        Which kind of profile would you like?
    </p>
</div>
<a href="@Url.Action("RegisterSenior", "Account", new RouteValueDictionary {{"userSide", "contractor" }})">
    <img src="images/signup-contractor.png" alt="mans's head sillouheted with safety helmet" title="As a Senior">
</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("RegisterEmployer", "Account", new RouteValueDictionary {{"userSide", "employer" }})">
    <img src="/Images/signup-employer.png" alt="mans's head sillouheted with collar and tie" title="As an Employer">
</a>
<div class="def-orange">    
    Already have an account?&nbsp;@Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "Account")
</div>
```

I know both images are present because I can swap them around, and both images display when they are on the right hand one of the two `a` tags, and neither displays when they are in the left hand `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `images/signup-contractor.png` to `/Images/signup-contractor.png`

Comment: The slash that nearly got away. Thanks.